# casperjs does not get $scope variables from AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, casperjs

I am using casperjs to simulate some tests. After the user logs in, the `login` should be changed to `Hi, {{username}}`. The casperjs only captures `Hi,` but does not get the username. So if let it give me the message, it tells me the actual value it gets is `Hi,` not `Hi, user_name`. Is there any mis-communication issue between casperjs and angularJS? How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Probably the same issue as with the previous question. What happens if you wait a little?

Comment: Hahah, I tried. I waited longer than usual (7s) but it doesn't work. Guess it is some other issue with AngularJS

Comment: Please register to the [`resource.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#resource-error), [`casper.page.onResourceTimeout`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html), [`remote.message`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#remote-message) and [`page.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error) events. Maybe there are errors.

Answer (score 0):

I got good results using [Resurrectio](https://github.com/ebrehault/resurrectio), the CasperJS test recorder Chrome extension. The first generated test within my AngularJS app used `casper.waitUntilVisible` and other async commands, so I never ran into that kind of issues. Maybe you can benefit from its use, too? Gave me a good starting point for my own tests.